# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' : Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' on the execution of my $params array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, api, error-handling

I've been getting this error for this line in my connect file :

$statement->execute($params);

Here is my connect file(btw I know what my credentials are I just didn't want to show it),

```
<?php
class connect
{

    private static function db()
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mysql;charset = utf8', 'username','password');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $pdo;
    }
    public static function query($query,$params = array())
    {

        $statement = self :: db()->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($params);
        if(explode(' ',$query)[0] == 'SELECT')
        {
            $data = $statement->fetchAll();
            return $data;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

However the problem stems from this call,

```
connect::query('INSERT INTO dry_posts VALUES (null, :postbody, NOW(), 0, \'\')', array(':postimg'=>$postimg));
```

That's from this file where I'm uploading and displaying images via the imgur api(this isn't the full file).

```
<?php 
include("connect.php"); 
include("check.php");
//include("image.php");

$postbody = "";
$posts = "";
$postimg = "";


                if (isset($_POST['post'])) {

                        if ($_FILES['postimg']['size'] == 0) 
                        {
                                $postbody = $_POST['postbody'];
                                $loggedInUserId = check::isLoggedIn();
                                if (strlen($postbody) > 160 || strlen($postbody) < 1) 
                                {
                                    die('Incorrect length!');
                                }

                                connect::query('INSERT INTO dry_posts VALUES (null, :postbody, NOW(), 0,:postimg)', array(':postbody'=>$postbody));

                                // Post::createPost($_POST['postbody']);

                        } 
                        else {

                            $url       = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image'; // API endpoints, info: https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image#image-upload
                    $client_id = '72316d91aac85c7'; // Get client_id here: https://api.imgur.com/#registerapp

                    $fh   = fopen($_FILES['postimg']['tmp_name'], 'r');
                    $read = fread($fh, $_FILES['postimg']['size']);
                    fclose($fh);
                    $post = array(
                                'image' => base64_encode($read)
                            );
                    $ch   = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                                             'Authorization: Client-ID '.$client_id
                                                         ));
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                    $json = curl_exec($ch); // Response, info: https://api.imgur.com/#responses
                    curl_close($ch);
                    // $image = json_decode($json, true); // Array
                    $image = json_decode($json); // Object
                    // var_dump($image);
                    //$postimg = $image['data']['link']; // Array-style
                    $postimg = $image->data->link; // Object-style


                                    // Insert $postimg to database?
                                    //connect::query('INSERT INTO dry_posts VALUES (null, :postbody, NOW(), 0, \'\')', array(':postimg'=>$postimg));
                    connect::query('INSERT INTO dry_posts VALUES (null, :postbody, NOW(), 0, :postimg)', array(':postimg'=>$postimg));
                                    //connect::query("UPDATE posts SET postimg=:postimg WHERE id=:postid", array(':postid' => $postid, ':postimg' => $postimg));
                            }


                        }

                if (isset($_GET['postid'])) 
                {
                        //Post::likePost($_GET['postid']);

                    if (!connect::query('SELECT post_id FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']))) 
                    {
                           connect::query('UPDATE dry_posts SET likes=likes+1 WHERE id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']));
                           connect::query('INSERT INTO post_likes VALUES (null, :postid)', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']));
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                          connect::query('UPDATE dry_posts SET likes=likes-1 WHERE id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']));
                          connect::query('DELETE FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']));
                    }

                    //Post::likePost($_GET['postid']);
                }

                // $posts = Post::displayPosts();

        //title is body or whereclause, search_results is posts or $paramsarray, results is paramsarray


                $dbposts = connect::query('SELECT * FROM dry_posts ORDER BY id DESC');
                $posts = "";
             //if(isset($_POST['postimg'])){ 
                foreach($dbposts as $p){
                        if (!connect::query('SELECT post_id FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$p['id']))) {
                                $posts .="<img src='".$p['postimg']."'>".htmlspecialchars($p['body'])."
                                <form action='try.php?postid=".$p['id']."' method='post'>
                                        <input type='submit' name='like' value='Like'>
                                        <span>".$p['likes']." likes</span>
                                </form>
                                <hr /></br />
                                ";

                        } else {
                                $posts .="<img src='".$p['postimg']."'>".htmlspecialchars($p['body'])."
                                <form action='try.php?postid=".$p['id']."' method='post'>
                                        <input type='submit' name='unlike' value='Unlike'>
                                        <span>".$p['likes']." likes</span>
                                </form>
                                <hr /></br />
                                ";
                        }
                }


?>

connect::query('SELECT body FROM dry_posts WHERE body LIKE :body '.$whereclause.'', $paramsarray);
```

I'm sure there's nothing wrong with the way I'm accepting parameters in my connect file since it works when I pass my $postbody array, so is there something wrong with the way postimg is defined, what am I missing? postimg is a input variable  from this form

```
<form action="try.php" class = "forum" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea name="postbody" rows="4" cols="60" class = "text"></textarea>
         <br />Upload an image:
        <input type="file" name="postimg">
        <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
connect::query('
    INSERT
    INTO   dry_posts
    VALUES (
        null,
        :postbody,  <-- you name your placeholder :postbody
        NOW(),
        0,
        \'\'
    )
', array(
    ':postimg' => $postimg  <-- you're trying to fill a placeholder named :postimg
));
```

Change your query to use `:postimg` as a placeholder, or change your array to try to fill the `:postbody` placeholder.

Comment: thanks that worked but, I'm having a problem storing it in to the postimg column in my mysql table dry_posts it's being stored into the postbody column instead, I tried using this call  :                           connect::query('INSERT INTO dry_posts VALUES (null, :postbody, NOW(), 0, :postimg)', array(':postimg'=>$postimg));   but the postimg column is set up as null by default, if I try to change that I get this error : query error : #1265 - Data truncated for column 'postimg' at row 1,   any sql statements to make this go away, sorry for all the extra

Comment: the last value in the insert statement is for postimg

Comment: So wouldn't it be `VALUES (null, \'\', NOW(), 0, :postimg)` then?

Comment: yeah I tried that but like I said the postimg column is set up as null by default, and if I try to change that I get this error : query error : #1265 - Data truncated for column 'postimg' at row 1,                                             are there any sql statements that you know to make this go away,

Comment: The `Data truncated` warning has nothing to with it being `NULL` by default. It means there's not enough room. Maybe you have it as a `VARCHAR(10)` and `$postimg` is 11 characters. Edit the column to make it bigger. Do `var_dump($postimg);` to see how big it is, compare that to how much room you have in your column.

Comment: Ok I've lost that truncate error now I get this for using the insert statement you suggested  : Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'

Comment: Are you still executing the query with an array containing only `array(':postimg' => $postimg)`? Or does it now have multiple entries?

Comment: there's just two other arrays passed in the query method one is the postbody array in the nested if statement, and this which is not shown   connect::query('INSERT INTO post_likes VALUES (null, :postid)', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']));

Comment: That's not what I meant. The error is saying that the number of placeholders in the query does not match the number of elements in the array. So, does your code match this: `connect::query('INSERT INTO dry_posts VALUES (null, \'\', NOW(), 0, :postimg)', array(':postimg' => $postimg));`?

Comment: ok thanks man that insert works but how come the images come out broken any idea? I'm sorry there's a lot of problems.

Comment: define "broken"?

Comment: like it won't show the actual image it just displays a broken page instead and if I post in to word or notepad the actual image shows

Comment: Nothing comes to mind. You should open a new question for that one.